# how can I get the fragment of the URL on first load in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-routing

I'm trying to get the fragment when the page first load but I'm getting undefined instead.

right now I'm subscribing to the  route service fragment and calling it on init.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public fragment;
    constructor(
        public route: ActivatedRoute   
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => {
            console.log(fragment) // undefined expecting the fragment route on load
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: i think you have to try like this `this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment: any) => { console.log(e); });`

Answer (score 2):

Implemented the interface `OnInit` within a component and then subscribe to the route fragment to get changes.

```
ngOnInit():void {
  this.route.fragment.subscribe(
    (fragment) => {
      this.setSegment(fragment);
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use **router.url**:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.url.subscribe(segments => {
        console.log(segments.map(x => x.toString()));
    });
}
```

**router.url** return an array of url's **segments**, so for instance, for url http://__.com/catalog/product it will return the next array ['catalog', 'product'].
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, sometimes angular just overcomplicates things.

```
ngOnInit():void {
    console.log("window.location.hash", window.location.hash.substring(1));
}
```

[image: prints]